# Debugging A Segmentation Fault in C Program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

What I am trying to do is to create a 10x10 array and only print out the values on the diagonal, it is currently segfaulting so I have a couple questions. 
1. What is the easiest way to debug a segfault on a Mac using a terminal shell? 
2. I'm trying to find out where in this function it segfaults? I tried adding a simple printf statement above the values = malloc... line and it didn't even make it that far I don't think.

```
int **values;

int i, j;
values = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        values[i][j] = i * j;
} 
}
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d ", values[i][i]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Use a debugger like GDB.

Comment: Try `int values[10][10];` and no malloc; or `int (*values)[10];` and values = malloc(10*10*sizeof(int));` . Also put `fflush(stdout);` after each debugging `printf`.

Comment: You've `malloc`d space for 10 pointers, but you never make them point to anything.

Comment: @Marian this is wrong: `malloc(10*10*sizeof(int *));`. Given the type preceding it, using `int (*values)[10] = malloc(10*sizeof(*values))` would be sufficient.

Comment: Y the hell are you changing your question altogether, after people started posting for you ?

Comment: removing your posted code makes related comments and answers inexplicable at best, irrelevant at worst. Don't do that.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a Mac running some version of OS X, you should have both gcc and gdb installed.  If not, they're easy to download and install.  I'm running on a Linux system, but the steps and output below should be similar on OS X.

In order to see your source code in the debugger, you'll have to compile it with the `-g` option: `gcc -o myprog -g myprog.c`.  Otherwise you'll only see the generated machine code.

At this point, you can either run the program normally and let it dump a core file which you'll load into gdb, or start the program up within gdb and step through it line by line.

I took the liberty of taking your code and creating a full program from it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
  int **values;

  int i, j;
  values = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
          values[i][j] = i * j;
      }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d ", values[i][i]);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

We'll build this with debugging enabled:

```
$ gcc -o example -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror example.c
```

and start it up within gdb:

```
$ gdb example
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.1-8.9.1)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-suse-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/fbgo448/prototypes/coredump/example...done.
(gdb)
```

First thing we'll do is set a breakpoint at `main`; this will cause the program to pause as soon as it enters the main function:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005a0: file example.c, line 9.
```

Now we'll start the program running within the gdb environment; it will run to the next breakpoint:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/fbgo448/prototypes/coredump/example

Breakpoint 1, main () at example.c:9
9         values = malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));
```

You can execute one line at a time, like so:

```
(gdb) n
10        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
```

You can examine the contents of variables or arbitrary memory locations:

```
(gdb) p values
$1 = (int **) 0x501010
(gdb) p *values
$2 = (int *) 0x0
(gdb) x/1x 0x501010
0x501010:       0x00000000
(gdb) x/1b 0x501010
0x501010:       0x00
(gdb) x/10b 0x501010
0x501010:       0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x501018:       0x00    0x00
(gdb) x/10x 0x501010
0x501010:       0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x501018:       0x00    0x00
```

Hopefully you see the problem already, but if not, we can "continue" the program and let it run until it fails:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005e3 in main () at example.c:12
12                values[i][j] = i * j;
```

You're getting a segfault trying to assign `values[i][j]`.  Let's take a look again:

```
(gdb) p i
$3 = 0
(gdb) p j
$4 = 0
(gdb) p values
$5 = (int **) 0x501010
(gdb) p values[i]
$6 = (int *) 0x0
(gdb) p values[i][j]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

Other people have pointed out the problem; you allocated enough space for 10 pointers to `int`, but you didn't allocate anything for those pointers to point *to*.  You're missing a step in your allocation process:

```
values = malloc( 10 * sizeof *values ); // sizeof *values == sizeof (int *)
if ( values )
{
  for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
  {
    values[i] = malloc( 10 * sizeof *values[i] ); // sizeof *values[i] == sizeof (int)
    if ( values[i] )
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
      {
         values[i][j] = i * j;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

gdb's a reasonably powerful debugger, if somewhat of a pain to use.

Comment: This comprehensive answer is still my guide to `gdb`. Thanks for this!

Comment: @wizzwizz4: You really want to use a [more authoritative reference](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).  My answer doesn't even begin to scratch the surface of how to use gdb.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate both "columns" and "rows". Right now you're only allocating pointers to integers, you also need to allocate the integers themselves.

```
int **values;

int i, j;
values = (int**)malloc(10 * sizeof(int *));

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    values[i] = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); //Small edit.
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        values[i][j] = i * j;
    } 
}
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d ", values[i][i]);
printf("\n");
```

I don't know much about Mac, but I'm pretty sure you can use [GDB](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=gdb%20tutorial). Compile your program with the debugging options to create an executable with debug info, and when the program crashes it will generate a core dump. Open this core dump with gdb and bon appetit.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault happens whenever your pointer has address which points to non-permissible memory segment. This situation happens when it is not initialized. Most of the time garbage value causes these kind of failure.

To avoid this, use calloc instead of malloc(), because `calloc()` allocates memory as well as initializes to zero.

Also you nees to allocate space for 2nd dimension.

```
int **values;

int i, j;
values = (int**)calloc(10 * sizeof(int *));

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    values[i] = (int*)calloc(10 * sizeof(int)); //Small edit.
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        values[i][j] = i * j;
    } 
}
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d ", values[i][i]);
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code would be the easiest way. Here is how:

```
int i, j;
values = malloc(10 * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    values[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        values[i][j] = i * j;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to `free` it all when you're done:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    free(values[i]);
}
free(values);
```

Comment: to free, all we have to do is free(10* sizeof(int*)).. you just free exactly what you malloc'd correct?

Comment: @user1837411 In this case to free this requires 11-invocations of `free()`; the same number of `free()`s as `malloc()`s.