# Does anyone know why is my program crashing?

Tags: c

I am trying to dynamically allocate words straight out of a txt file for further use, but after entering the file name, the program crashes and returns a negative value (CodeBlocks). Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define L 18
#define F 50    
int main()
    {
        char **text = NULL;
        int wcount=0;
        text = textInput(&wcount);
        free(text);
    
        return 0;
    }
    
    char** textInput(int *wcount)
    {
        FILE *loadfile;
        char fname[F];
        char *word;
        char **text;
        printf("\nType the file of the name you would like to load: ");
        scanf("%49s", fname);
        strcat(fname, ".txt");
        if((loadfile = fopen(fname, "rt")) == NULL)
            perror("Cannot open file");
        while(fscanf(loadfile,"%18s", word = (char*)malloc(L*sizeof(char)))!= EOF)
        {
            (*wcount)++;
            text = (char**)realloc(text, (*wcount)*sizeof(char *));
            text[(*wcount)-1] = word;
        }
        fclose(loadfile);
        free(word);
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to have the tag of the language you're using, rather than C#?

Comment: What is the value of `F`?

Comment: my bad, i thought c# was the appropriate tag for c

Comment: forgot to add all the #include and #define lines

Comment: Use your debugger.  Step through the code.  First step: *YOU MUST IDENTIFY THE SPECIFIC LINE THAT'S FAILING*.  You need to know exactly *what* is failing (which line) and, ideally, *why* (e.g. a segmentation violation). Using the debugger is a good way to do this.

Comment: Off by one: `"%18s"` should be `"%17s"`, but got it right with `"%49s"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging A Segmentation Fault in C Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437227/debugging-a-segmentation-fault-in-c-program)

Comment: be careful with `fname`. It's good that you're thinking about staying in bounds with `%49s`, but then you go and tack on `.txt` to it. If the user maxes out 49, that will overflow.

Comment: thanks for the tips, i solved the problem, turns out I missed the initialization of the  text pointer as the first answer points out

Comment: There is really no point in using pre-processor macros to define constants like L and F if you are going to hard-code the width modifier on the conversion specifier for the scanf format string.  Either dynamically build the format string (eg `sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", M - 1);`) or just *stop* *using* *scanf*.  Attempts to use scanf correctly generally wind up being almost as much code as other parsing methods (eg `%d` leads to UB on certain inputs, so you need to add logic to prevent that which usually means building a format string) and are less educational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `textInput`, you haven't initialized `text` before calling `realloc(text, ...)`.
Add the initialization `text = NULL` before calling `realloc`.  E.g.

```
char **text = NULL;
```

You already have a line like that in `main()`, but in `main()` it doesn't matter, the variable `text` in `main()` is not the same as the variable `text` in `textInput()`. (Also, in `main()`, you reassign `text` before you attempt to use it, so the initialization of `text` to `NULL` is not required.)

Comment: Dang, it seems like this was the problem, thank you very much for pointing it out, should've examined it more